# Using jQuery's .slideToggle() on Wordpress Categories

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to get the Categories and Archives sidebar sections on a Wordpress site (http://stoganews.com/) to display only when hovered over, using jQuery's `.slideToggle()`.

Here is the relevant HTML, from the Categories list.
The Archives list has exactly the same structure.

```html
<div class="catlist">
 <ul class="cats-list">
  <li>
   <h2><a href="#">CATEGORIES</a></h2>
   <ul class="list-alt">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-71">
     <a href="http://stoganews.com/?cat=71" title="View all posts filed under Arts &amp; Culture">Arts &amp; Culture</a> (28)
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-130">
     ...
```

This is the Javascript I am using, in [expand.js](http://stoganews.com/wp-content/themes/premiumnews/includes/js/expand.js).

```js
jQuery('.catlist').each(function(){
   // hides Categories section, Archives section
   jQuery('.list-alt',this).hide();

   // show section when hovered over
   jQuery(this).hover(function(){
      jQuery(this).find('.list-alt').toggle();
   });
});
```

As you can see from the site, the code currently works with `toggle()`. But when I substitute `slideToggle()` for `toggle()`, the sections are never hidden, and nothing happens when they are hovered over. Why?

Issues I've made sure to avoid:

- jQuery is indeed included. It shows up in the source code as `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://stoganews.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>`.
- As far as I know, I am not using fixed panels, which cannot be animated.
- I have used `jQuery()` instead of `$()` - this is a limitation of Wordpress.

P.S. My first question on stackoverflow!

Comment: please note that the submenu is shown, but I can't click on it because it disappears before my mouse can hover over it, tested in latest version of Opera

Comment: @Dorin Thanks, I'll make sure to test the final version using Opera. Right now, I don't why that is the case - this should be a fairly standard application of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [jsfiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/dalziel/J8LC4/) it seems to work. They don't have jquery 1.6.1, the demo there is using 1.6.4.  I did need to change `jQuery('.catlist')` to `jQuery('.cats-list')` on the 1st line of the javascript, it may have been that which is stopping it from working.

Comment: Yeah, when the code is isolated, it should work. The problem is probably due to a conflict with Wordpress or a Wordpress plugin - does Wordpress have its own version of jQuery? For the next day or so, I'll change toggle() to slideToggle() on the live site, if that helps.

Comment: Yes, it does have it's own version of jQuery. Try not including yours and see if it works.

Comment: @Glenn Unfortunately, `.catlist` is not the problem - I forgot to include the outer `<div class="catlist">` in the snippet.

Comment: There are a bunch of JS errors occurring on that page, you may want to fix them as that can stop JS from binding

Comment: @CookiesForDevo I actually don't know how to change that. `header.php` includes the line `<?php wp_head(Stoganews.com); ?>`, but I have no idea where that points to.

Also, changing the jQuery version would certainly help find where the problem is occurring, but other plugins probably rely on the custom version, so I don't think I could change it permanently.

Comment: It may be the easing plugin, I just ran `jQuery('.list-alt').slideToggle();` directly on your page & got "Object #<Object> has no method 'swing'".  I don't think you need that now. also you're including 2 jquery libraries, from your content folder, plus the one from wordpress include.  Stop including yours, and remove the reference to the easing plugin.

Comment: @AllenZ. There are two version of jQuery running. Check your theme footer.php file and comment out <script type="text/javascript" src="http://stoganews.com/wp-content/themes/premiumnews/includes/js/jquery-1.1.3.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @GlennSlaven Using Chrome's Developer Tools, I see two JS errors, which I believe relate to the navigation bar. I am hesitant to fix these errors at the moment since, as far as I can tell, the navigation bar (1) works, and (2) comes with the theme. I have not yet fully understood the theme, since I started as volunteer webmaster for this site just this week.

Comment: Awesome, @CookiesForDevo and GlennSlaven - the code now works as intended. Removing those two lines probably broke something else, but I'll cross that bridge when I get to it.